# Check for coincident points (within tolerance)

Tags: python, geometry

I'd like to check if two points are identical within an absolute tolerance value in the most 'pythonic' and simple way.

I am currently using 'numpy' built-in function `allclose()`:

`numpy.allclose(a, b, 0, tol)`

But I am looking for a 'non-numpy' solution if possible.

**Example**

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1.1, 2.1, 3.1]
c = [1, 3, 3]
tolerance = 0.5
```

`a` compared to `b` should return `true`

`a` compared to `c` should return `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two dimensions you can use:

```
>>> import math
>>> same = lambda p1, p2, tol: math.hypot(p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] - p1[1]) <= tol
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [1.1, 2.1]
>>> c = [1, 3]
>>> same(a, b, 0.5)
True
>>> same(b, c, 0.5)
False
>>>
```

And for more:

```
multiHypot = lambda diffs: math.sqrt(sum(diff**2 for diff in diffs))
same = lambda p1, p2, tol: multiHypot(p2[i] - p1[i] for i in range(len(p1))) <= tol
```

**Update per Rockcat's comment (more efficient):**

```
same = lambda p1, p2, tol: sum((p2[i] - p1[i])**2 for i in range(len(p1))) <= tol**2
```

A prettier version (maybe faster):

```
from operator import sub
same = lambda p1, p2, tol: sum(x**2 for x in map(sub, p1, p2)) <= tol**2
```

Comment: In general, it is better to avoid hypot(x) and other functions based on sqrt(x) when comparing a threshold due to perfomance and round-off errors. Instead of `sqrt(x) <= tolerance`, you should use  `x <= tolerance**2`